# what is the fastest way for fulltext search?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, full-text-search

I wanna do fulltext search (on some keywords) with text rows in file.

currently we're using RDB(MySQL), but it takes a while. I want it faster.

It occurs to me to use Hadoop, but its performance improvement is not that good when compared to the cost. (as the number of machine increase, the performance will become 1/n + some overhead... I guess.)

Any better solutions?

Comment: if you are using AWS, Amazon cloudsearch should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at SOLR/Lucene?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for some GUI based solution to be used personally, then try using [SQLyog's](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) data search feature with MySQL. It performs search very similar to Google Search... It is very easy and intuitive to use. It is worth giving a try...

[image: SQlyog Datasearch screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You should try Sphinx with MySQL. It's best for the full text searching and its open source software, also syntax is very similar to MySQL.

[Sphinx search engine wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_%28search_engine%29)

[Sphinx web site](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at SaaS solutions? I am owner of http://IndexDen.com, but also you can look at: Searchify or Websolr.